# Question about root rights

Tags: terminal, network, bash, homebrew, permission

I have a question about this post and it says that if you want to leave out the "sudo" in front of it, the following is described

[how to run `hping` without `sudo`](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/304106/how-to-run-hping-without-sudo)

`sudo chown root:wheel /usr/local/Cellar/hping/3.20051105/sbin/hping3`

`sudo chmod u+s /usr/local/Cellar/hping/3.20051105/sbin/hping3`

Now comes what I don't quite understand.

Is it correct that hping is allowed to run with root rights only because root is the owner?

It is still far from being authorized it is only said that root can make changes to this file or do I get it wrong?

Comment: I see three questions here. Any chance you could remove the hypothetical “am I wrong” and then focus on one problem per question?

Comment: When I run hping, an error message appears because I do not have the required rights. So I have to put a sudo in front of it so that hping can run.

But then I saw a post that I linked above. There it was shown that you can run the file without sudo with chown root.

Now I don't quite understand why it can run without sudo because it only belongs to root but that it also has root rights is something else?

Comment: Ok - if no one answers in a week, consider an edit to the question body would be my advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User [Richard Wick](https://superuser.com/users/898017/richard-wicks) posted an [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/457868/making-a-program-always-run-as-root-in-os-x/1316546#1316546) which explains that the command has to call the [setuid](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man2/setegid.2.html) function in order to elevate the privileges of the command.

So changing command ownership to root and adding the `s` bit to the command's file mode is not enough. The command itself must also be written to ask the operating system for root privileges.